# How to solve low performance on Ubuntu 15.10 with nVidia 650M, various drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 15.10

Last week I installed a SSD and formated my Ubuntu 14.04.3 to install Ubuntu 15.10 with UEFI, *root* and *swap* on SSD, */home* on HDD, overall disk access speed much better. But the problem is: graphics become so much slow, it freezes on single and network games (tested on XCOM, Civ5, Dota2), timouting on the last.

I emphasize that it not happened on Ubuntu 14.04.3 within the same conditions and same driver.

I tried everything I could, reformatted and reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10 two times and I would thank you very much if you have any clue how to solve this problem.

nvidia-352 was apt-got with xorg-edgers PPA added, all times.

**I gave up on Optimus technology a long time ago, my notebook is used as a compact wired desktop, so, no problem, let the battery go.**

> - $ lspci | grep VGA
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)
>
> - $ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf | grep version
>
> version 352.63  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-11)  Sat Nov  7 22:00:19 PST 2015
>
> - $ glxinfo
>
> http://pastebin.com/1hNmsxPT
>
> - $ ubuntu-drivers devices
>
> == cpu-microcode.py ==
>   driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free
>
> == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
>   vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
>
> model    : GK107M [GeForce GT 650M]
>
> modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000FD1sv000014C0sd00000066bc03sc00i00
>
> driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
>
> driver   : nvidia-340-updates - distro non-free
>
> driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
>
> driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
>
> driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
>
> **driver   : nvidia-352-updates - distro non-free**
>
> driver   : nvidia-352 - distro non-free recommended

Tried all seven drivers, same problem.

Typical conditions with Sync to VBlank enabled. Some FPS drops on glxgears, but during freezes it won't drop enough to justify, stays almost the same. Temperature is normal. CPU is a Intel Core i7-3630QM.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIdTI.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories. But when there are problems with the drivers ... you can install the more current drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA.

Uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers and remove the xorg-edgers PPA.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo reboot
```

You can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers that support GEFORCE GT 650M.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hi, netbox, that's a good PPA. Graphics looking better and I think freezing diminishes, but still happening on heavy moments, like MOBA teamfights. Is there anything else I can do? Tomorrow I will try a clean install with this PPA.

Comment: @rmagnelli : I am glad to read this,  the clean installation is really a good idea. NVIDIA improves the drivers continuously - so you should always upgrade to new drivers as soon as they are provided through the GPU Drivers PPA ... enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)